# consulta a base de datos oracle

Tags: oracle

Buenas tardes necesito hacer una consuilta a una base de datos de oracle, y pues me muestra este error

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   933 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:159) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\oracle\conexion.php:40 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\oracle\conexion.php(40): PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\oracle\conexion.php on line 40

```
<?php
$pagination = new PDO_Pagination($connection);
$contador=1;
$search= null;
$start= null;


    $pagination->rowCount('SELECT NOMBRE FROM MATERIAPRIMA ');
    $pagination->config(8, 10);
    $sql = "SELECT NOMBRE FROM MATERIAPRIMA  LIMIT  $pagination->start_row, $pagination->max_rows";
    $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

    $model = array();

    while($rows = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
    $model[] = $rows;
    }

  ?>

    <tr class="active">
    <thead>
    <th>#</th>    
    <th>CÓDIGO</th>
    <th>INSUMO</th>
    <th>USO</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    foreach($model as $row)
    {
    $contador ='#';
     echo "<tbody id='timeReals'>";  
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>".$contador."</td>";        
     echo "<td>".$row['CODIGO']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$row['NOMBRE']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$row['IDUSO']."</td>";
     $contador++;
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    echo "<center>";
    $pagination->pages("bt");
    echo "</center>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual es la consulta que estas tratando de ejecutar? hace un echo de tu consulta por favor

Answer (score 1):

No soy experto en programacion, pero en oracle todos los comandos deben de terminar con ";" y en ninguno de tus queries lo veo. ¿Trataste ya de  incluir el ";" directamente en el query?

Por ejemplo:

$pagination->rowCount('SELECT NOMBRE FROM MATERIAPRIMA; ');

Comment: de donde hablas? yo veo punto y coma en sus sentencias

Comment: En tu cadena $sql que contiene el query necesita al final el ";"  dentro de la consulta

Comment: @shadow, por favor revisa mi comentario anterior donde digo "Por ejemplo", y luego comparalo con la linea original. Lo mismo pasa con el 2o query.